# Populate condition expression

Tags: web2py

is that possible in a web2py to populate a field with a condition expression dependent of another field as if row.field make such a calculation is True otherwise make such a calculation

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use a [computed field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Computed-fields):

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('field1'),
    Field('field2', compute=lambda r: 'this' if r.field1 else 'that'))
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you antony 
i have probleme this code

```
Field ('heure','boolean',compute=lambda r: True if r.date3 <= 23 else False)
```

i want put False or True according the value row date3 but it put me by default False